# Does anyone know what jiahuiyu's slimmable_ Ops file is?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

```
from .slimmable_ops import SwitchableBatchNorm2d
from .slimmable_ops import SlimmableConv2d, SlimmableLinear
from .slimmable_ops import pop_channels
from utils.config import FLAGS
```

Recently, I want to reproduce jiahuiyu's slimmable_ networks.When I use autoslim_ mobilenet_ Errors will be reported when training V1 model. No, slimmable_ Ops library file.
What should I do.

Comment: You mean this? https://github.com/JiahuiYu/slimmable_networks/blob/master/models/slimmable_ops.py

Comment: I didn't notice the point in front of .slimmable_ops when I reproduced the network.He doesn't seem to want to be the correct syntax for Python 3.After I delete it, the program can run normally.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but you have to execute the code in the correct way. How are you doing that?

Comment: This may be because there is no __ init__. py in the models folder.

Comment: You're right. There's nothing wrong with the grammar. I just created one __ init__.py file in the models folder, there is no error.